# How to define a database audit specification 'BY Any User'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, audit

I want to track inserts updates and deletes on a number of tables.  What I currently have is

```
ALTER DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION [mySpec]

ADD (INSERT ON OBJECT::[dbo].[SomeTable] BY [SomeUser]),
ADD (UPDATE ON OBJECT::[dbo].[SomeTable] BY [SomeUser]),
ADD (DELETE ON OBJECT::[dbo].[SomeTable] BY [SomeUser]),

... More Tables ..

WITH (STATE = ON);
```

Is there a set of Principals that would equate to "Any User" that I can use instead of the 'SomeUser' in my script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `public` group

eg:

```
ALTER DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION [mySpec]
ADD (INSERT ON OBJECT::[dbo].[SomeTable] BY [public])
...
```

or any other group that all your users belong to.

You can also group the events you want to audit,

```
ALTER DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION [mySpec]
ADD (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON OBJECT::[dbo].[SomeTable] BY [public])
...
```

If you want to audit all the tables you can use the database object

```
ALTER DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION [mySpec]
ADD (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON DATABASE::databasename BY [public])
...
```

Comment: So there can be no user who is not a member of [public] ?

Comment: because I wasnt 100% sure from the documentation

Comment: @HughJones "Every SQL Server login belongs to the public server role" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/server-level-roles

Comment: thanks.  I am accepting your answer, but I am massively disappointed to find that the audit does not record parameter values for statements - this renders it entirely useless.

Comment: It is rather, isn't it. Perhaps CDC is better suited to your needs  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server

Comment: I am investigating that now